# How do I send messages to the "Posts" tab of a channel in Teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to follow the code on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#permissions-for-chat

When I first loaded my app and triggered the notification code, I got a 403 error:

> Error: Missing role permissions on the request. API requires one of 'Teamwork.Migrate.All'.

After I added "Teamwork.Migrate.All" to the permissions in Azure, I got a 401 error:

> Error: Message POST is allowed in application-only context only for import purposes. Refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams for more details.

So I guess I have three related questions.

1. How do I make this API work?
2. What does it mean to "import" a team? I don't want to import messages, I want to create new messages in an existing team.
3. If this API doesn't work for what I want, how can I send messages to a channel's "Posts" tab without using an Incoming Webhook?

This is the code I'm trying to use.

```
const options = {
    authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

const chatMessage = {
  body: {
    content: 'Hello World'
  }
};

await client.api('/teams/${teamId}/channels/${channelId}/messages')
    .post(chatMessage);
```

Comment: #2: Do you mean "*"import" a message*"? You are importing _messages_ here, not _a team_, from another system here into Teams.

Comment: To assist with why your API call isn't working, we'll need to see your API code (with any secrets/keys/other sensitive data stripped out). See [mre] for more info. And I'm assuming you're using JavaScript to make this call, since you linked to the JavaScript version of the Docs page?

Comment: When I searched for the "import purposes" message I found some documentation about "setting a team to import mode". Sorry if that was confusing. Yes, I mean importing messages. I don't want to import messages, I want to create new ones from my app.

Yes, I'm using the Javascript calls. I have done nothing different from the first example. I'll add the code to my original question.

Comment: I see--there may be some confusion. The Import API functionality linked in the second error message is specifically for creating a new, back-dated team and importing historical messages into it _once_, and then 'publishing' the team for general use/consumption. You cannot use it to send new messages into an existing team. [1/3]

Comment: It seems the article there is in need of editing as well... it says "*Note: Application permissions are only supported for migration. In the future, Microsoft may require you or your customers to pay additional fees based on the amount of data imported.*" So giving the `Teamwork.Migrate.All` permission would work... if you were doing a back-dated migration into a new team. But you don't want to do that. [2/3]

Comment: The only other options for doing this are ones the page lists as _deprecated_,which is frustrating: `ChannelMessage.Send` and `Group.ReadWrite.All` permissions. Try adding those permissions instead of the `Teamwork.Migrate.All` permission and see what error message you get. I guess they have marked that permission as deprecated because they plan to charge money for real-time external message feed functionality eventually, but just haven't had time to implement that yet... [3/3]

Comment: I tried adding `ChannelMessage.Send` and I got the original 403 error again: "Error: Missing role permissions on the request. API requires one of 'Teamwork.Migrate.All'."

Comment: Looks like it may be broken then... I haven't used the API before to perform that action so I'm not sure when it changed. Another user also reported the same issue on the Microsoft Answers site a couple of weeks ago: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1338427/unable-to-post-message-to-teams-channel-using-grap If you have a paid account, it might be worth logging a request in the M365 Admin Center under the Teams or Graph category and mention this issue... it may well require internal Microsoft support to fix.

Comment: Then again, even back in 2021 [this employee said](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/659198/issue-sending-message-to-an-ms-teams-channel-via-g#answer-670108) the same thing about only being allowed in migration mode, adn that you need to use delegated permissions via something like Power Automate, and login as a user, but that seems counterintuitive compared to an that purports to have this feature API, the whole point of which is to avoid having user accounts to do things.

Comment: @JoshBrown -Application permissions are only supported when team is under migration mode as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#permissions-for-chat) . You need to use delegated permissions as suggested above.

Comment: If you read all my comments you would see that I tried adding delegated permissions and still got an error.

Comment: Okay using those delegated permissions you are getting `403 error`. From your code snippet it seems like the API call is being made in Application context. Please refer [this response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/659198/issue-sending-message-to-an-ms-teams-channel-via-g#answer-670108) from engineering team where it is being explained what to use and what not.